# Hasmany relationship in ember with array id

Tags: postgresql, ember.js, foreign-keys, relationship

I have some trouble with has_many relationship in ember,
let's say I want to retrieve the comments attached to a post, I can easily do it if my Postgres schema looks like this:

**posts:**

```
{
  id: 1,
  comments: [1, 2, 3]
}
```

**comments:**

```
{
  id: 3,
  post_id: 1
}
```

But what I want is to get rid of the "comments" in posts table, like:

**posts:**

```
{
  id: 1
}
```

**comments**

```
{
  id: 3,
  post_id: 1
}
```

So far I haven't found anything that can help me even if it doesn't seem hard :(

I would be glad if someone can help me do that :)

Answer (score 0):

What i wanted to do was not possible without overriding a big piece of ember-data,

So i will get my records like that:

```js
let campaignId = 1;

this.store.query('stat', {campaign_id: campaignId});
```